# ORDER BY datetime but keep records with same TITLE on top of each other

Tags: mysql

I have table like

```
test
+---------------------+-------+
| date_in             | title |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | foo   |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | bar   |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | man   |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | foo   |
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | test  |
+---------------------+-------+
```

my desired result is

```
+---------------------+-------+
| date_in             | title |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2018-01-05 00:00:00 | test  |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00 | foo   | -- see this
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | foo   | -- see this
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00 | man   |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00 | bar   |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I have tried below query and other several queries but it doesn't work

```
select * from test order by title, date_in desc
```

Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd33f/4 SQLFiddle with schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to order by three columns.

1. the date_in for which each title first appeared.
2. the title itself
3. the date_in for each row

You need to generate the first of these three in your query. To do this you write a subquery and join it, as if it were a virtual table, to your table.

This subquery does the trick. It gives one row per title, showing the first date the title appeared. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd33f/23/0)

```
select min(date_in) firstdate, 
       title
  from test
 group by title
```

You join that to your main table. Here's the whole query.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd33f/22/0)

```
select detail.* 
  from test detail
  join  (select min(date_in) firstdate, 
                title
            from test
           group by title
         ) firstdate on detail.title = firstdate.title 
  order by firstdate.firstdate, detail.title, detail.date_in
```

**If the subquery is slow** try creating an index on `(title, date_in)`. That kind of query uses a so-called [*loose index scan*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) and should be reasonably fast.

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX test_title_date (title,date_in);
```

Comment: This subquery takes forever with >100k records. I wonder if there is a nicer solution

Comment: I think I would just go with my old solution, that is `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(title) FROM table GROUP BY title ORDER BY date_in DESC` and then explode grouped results, but still if there is a MySQL solution I would love to hear that.

Comment: Please see my edit. And, if you still have performance problems it might be worthwhile to look at `EXPLAIN` output and even ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,this is using subquery,if that was not a problem ,you can try this

```
SELECT test.* FROM (select MAX(date_in) as temp_date_in,title from
test GROUP BY title order by  date_in desc) as temp JOIN test ON
temp.title = test.title ORDER BY temp.temp_date_in DESC,test.date_in DESC
```

**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1dd33f/72**

Comment: This subquery takes forever with >100k records. I wonder if there is a nicer solution

Comment: is there anything can do with stored procedures?